# Unexpected results form jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an ajax call under a function called refreshClick that is meant to fill a div with a select box that is generated by php.

Javascript:

```
           function refreshClick() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "modules/elements/customersList.php",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#refreshdiv').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="refreshdiv">test</div>
```

PHP:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $returnString .= '<option value="'.$row['customerid'].'" data-tokens="'.$row['Phone'].$row['customerid'].$row['Email'].$row['ID'].$row['alt1Name'].$row['alt1Info'].$row['alt2Name'].$row['alt2Info'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
}
echo '<select data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" data-selected-text-format="count > 1" style="width:100%" name="customer">';
echo $returnString;
echo '</select>';
```

So as you can see this code is pretty simple. I cannot for the life of my figure out whats going wrong. I have a button just above the `refreshdiv` div that calls the `refreshClick()` function, but when I click it the word `test` disappears. It LOOKS like it just clears out the div, but if I Inspect Element, I can see that the div was filled the way it was suppose to be, with the correct data aswell, but nothing is visable. Could someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Side note: The reason I want to use it this way is so I can call this function any time to refresh the contents of the select box, so that way if whoever is using the software updates the customer list they can refresh the select box without refreshing the page. If there is an easier way to do this, please enlighten me.

--Test data screenshot
This is `console.log(typeof data)` and `console.log(data)`
[image]

--Inspect element screenshot
(Ignore the hideous refresh button, it's temporary.) I would also like to include, in the page before I click the refresh button the word "Test" shows in the `refreshdiv` div. It DOES show.
[image]

Comment: Try `console.log`ging your `data` variable. I'm pretty sure the callback for those jQuery ajax functions is not the string result per si, but a more complex object contained the aforementioned and other data like status code.

Comment: @LuanNico But when I inspect element its all there correctly? Could that still be?

Comment: *if I Inspect Element, I can see that the div was filled the way it was suppose to be* can you post some print screen of this inspection?

Comment: console.log(data)

Comment: It's hard to guess by your description.... Maybe you have some CSS that hides all `select`s? You must be able to isolate the problem: try console.logging, hardcoding a select just like the one you should see, etc.

Comment: @mrlew Unfortunately it contains customer information. But it shows it exactly like it would be in HTML with no line breaks.

Comment: Try replacing `<div id="refreshdiv">test</div>` in your HTML by hand with the select copied from dev tools, then remove the call to your refresh function and see if it renders correctly.

Comment: @LuanNico It was hardcoded originally. That was my starting point. I know I don't have any CSS hiding it, because it worked fine hardcoded. Does the php page have to link to the CSS by itself?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton are you using real data in your dev env? you can hardcode some fake output just for test

Comment: @LuanNico I copied the console.log output exactly into the HTML page, and it displayed just fine.

Comment: @mrlew read my last comment to LuanNico please. The data being generated is fine

Comment: Do this then: `console.log(typeof data)`. But it'd be nice if you could mock some data to run proper tests, and send us some prints. You shouldn't be using production values in dev anyway.

Comment: @LuanNico typeof reports it as a string. I will mock up some data

Comment: Probably upon doing so you'll already find out what's wrong. But either way, send us a print!

Comment: @LuanNico I haven't. It all looks fine to me. Post updated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the `format="count > 1"` part. this > is going to get confused as the ending of the <select tag.

Comment: @LuanNico I thought "OF course! That has to be correct, it makes so much sense" - but alas, removing that bit of code did nothing

Comment: I threw together a test for your case and it seems to render fine if I hard code the `<option>`s, so the problem is probably  somewhere else, like the library using that odd `data-selected-text-format` markup.

Comment: @ppajer Must that library be included on the PHP page, or only on the page its actually rendering on? I assumed not as that would then be included in the output.

Comment: can post the print of your inspect element with the developer tool open? maybe some clue there

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Only on the rendering page. Anyway it looks like we were wrong about that attr being the problem.

Comment: Added the picture.

Comment: You could try isolating the problem further by removing all attributes from the select except `name`. That should rule out any outside code messing with it.

Comment: @ppajer Okay so that made the dropdown show. So it must be outside code for some reason? hmm

Comment: thanks. As we can see, the elements are there. Looks like your problem is styling (js or css hiding someway). You can try force removing that class `selectpicker` in the dev tool. Also, If you hover over the element in inspection, the browser shows where is it. Maybe can give us a clue.

Comment: @mrlew Removing `selectpicker` displayed the dropdown. So the selectpicker class allows bootstraps `bootstrap-select` addon work, which is crucial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, you are using bootstrap. That's the problem. Bootstrap needs to init every select. It does on startup, but every time it changes you need to run:

```
$(select).selectpicker('refresh');
```

To re-init the new ones.

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much! I can't give you enough checkmarks!

Comment: Yes, hurray :) I've fallen into this before myself, but totally forgot, should have remembered sooner. The reason for this is because `select` are not 100% customizable in every browser, so bootstrap needs to replace then with plain divs and JS code to look that pretty. So the CSS hides the original select, and the value is bound to the fake display select. If the 'create the fake divs' code is not run, though, only the CSS hides the original part will apply, leaving nothing on screen.